# How to use Bootstrap in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, phpstorm

How can I use Bootstrap in PhpStorm?

I did install Bootstrap with npm successfully but if I write a simple bootstrap command in the index.php
it is just a simple non effected grey small button.

example a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">test</button>
```

What am I missing in PhpStorm?

Comment: Did you `<link>`  the stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to link the `*.css` files to your page via `<link>` tag, like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">`.
Please check the [tutorial](https://websitesetup.org/bootstrap-tutorial-for-beginners/) and [the cheatsheet](https://websitesetup.org/bootstrap-cheat-sheet/) - you may find these resources helpful. See also https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/guide/tips/library-completion/

Answer (score 5):

**step 1** (if you use CDN lib):
[image]
**step 2:**
Going to Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript -> Libraries and checking enabled 'Bootstrap' if it isn't already.

Comment: If you want the "Download Library" button to appear directly when the link is hovered over as described above, make sure that the <style> or <script> tags are within the <html> tags. Otherwise, it didn't work for me.